# Saving a text from EditText into the Android internal Storage

Tags: android, storage, android-edittext, filenotfoundexception, internal

So I want to save whatever users write in their EditText to be saved for the next time. This exact same code works for java project but with Android project, it doesnt work.

The code is below.

The PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("hi"); always gives the FileNotFoundException e.

In java project, this code The PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("hi"); makes a new file with the name "hi" but android project does not produce a new file instead returns the error. It does not save the String from the EditText to be opened when the app opens up again later.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
 public void onCreate(blablabla)
 {blablabla
   try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader ("hi");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
        String line = in.nextLine();
        mEditText.setText(line);
        in.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        mEditText.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


   @Override    
protected void onDestroy() 
{        
    super.onDestroy();        
    // The activity is about to be destroyed.  
    try {                           
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("hi");
        out.write(mEditText.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Can't save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class aef {

 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  
  
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Output");
  out.write("asdfafkdjnasdfasdf");
  out.close();
  
  
  FileReader reader = new FileReader("Output");
  
  Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
  String line = in.nextLine();
  System.out.println(line);
  
  
  
  
  
  
 }

}
 THis java project Works FINE

Comment: Have you read about SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

May be Android permission problem. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms

Or better to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?